# Get Request.Form.Item by matching Request.Form.Key

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My Request.Form keys are all prefixed with ctl00$container name$ and *then* the key I want.
How can I get the regular key name working?

Visual example from the immediate window:

I want to use:

```
? request.Form.Item("stationIdea")
```

but it won't work because the key is:

```
ctl00$content_innovation_body$stationIdea
```

as retrieved by

```
? request.Form.Keys("4")
```

so only this works:

```
? request.Form("ctl00$content_innovation_body$stationIdea")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.Form(stationIdea.UniqueID)`

The `UniqueID` property will return the id you are looking for.  Another property you may be interested in is `ClientID` which can be useful for using the id in javascript.